# I'm not able to record Phone call in below and above Marshmallow?

Tags: android, phone-call, call-recording

I am trying to record a phone call in Android.
Firstly I have started searching the code for above Marshmallow, but I have found that Google has disabled the API for Phonecall above Marshmallow,
then I am the same code which I have written is not working below Marshmallow(I am running in Lollipop) which is not working

I am using Broadcastreceiver for detecting Phonecalls, It is working fine. Whenever phonecall is started I am using below code for start recording Phonecall and creating a folder of "CALL LOG", in which each call record will be stored.

```
public void startRecordingStoreFile(){

String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
        File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/CALLLOG");
        if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
            sampleDir.mkdirs();
        }
        String file_name = "Rec_"+out;
        try {
            audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());

 try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        recorder.start();
        recordstarted = true;
}
```

Below code for stopping the record

```
public void stopRecording(){
        if (recordstarted) {
            recorder.stop();
            audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
            recordstarted = false;
        }
    }
```

Above code is not recording the audio of a phone call, it is creating a folder of "CALL LOG" and ".amr" files are stored but audio is not recording. I was working on this for 2 days.

For example, suppose let's say I am calling to "X" person, 
1.MIC is not recording once the "X"(other) person lift the call until then audio is recording some times,

I am unable to record audio of Incoming and outgoing calls. Some times it works, sometimes it is not working. Please help me with this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: For security purposes you aren't allowed to record phone calls.  Nor is that what your code is trying to do-  its using the mic as the data source.  So you *may* get some phone sounds if the volume of the device is way up or on speaker phone.  But its going to be recording local sounds from the microphone, which would likely result in 1 side of the conversation.

Comment: But there are applications in playstore working fine.I have a requirement so I have to do it.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, is it completely not allowed or we can still use below Marshmallow ?

Comment: This code was never assured to work, on any version of Android.  It *might* work, depending on how loud the call is.  But its a crap shoot.

Comment: Can you please help me on this if you have any idea ?